# Error message when performing show segue and save userdefault: View is not in the window heirarch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a problem with the alert not displaying. I know it works because it prints to my console. I also tested the alertpopup in a viewDidAppear method and it worked. I've read some post and it maybe because of me trying to perform a segue and save a userdefault at the same time. I keep getting "Warning: Attempt to present... whose view is not in the window hierarchy". Any way to fix it or an explanation of what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class StartMenuViewController : UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var nameInput: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func startAction(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if nameInput.text == ""
        {
            print("This is working")
            createAlert(title: "Warning", message: "Need to enter name")
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(nameInput.text, forKey: "UserName")
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {


        if let name = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserName") as? String
        {
            nameInput.text = name
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createAlert (title: String, message: String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling alert.dismiss. It will dismiss itself. P.S. This has nothing to do with a segue, you have no segue anywhere in your code.

Comment: Does the button that has `startAction` IBAction performing a segue?

Comment: @AhmadF Yes it does perform a segue

Comment: @Half man I perform a segue in the storyboard. I didn't code it. The alert.dismiss is used for when the alert message is displayed and the user taps the "OK" button.

Comment: At the next run of the app, does user defaults has a value for a key "UserName"? it should... you are getting the warning because you are pushing/presenting to a new view controller and presenting an alert view simultaneously

Comment: @AhmadF You maybe right. Once the app is terminated the UserDefaults are cleared but not before that. However I did remove the all the code pertaining to the UserDefaults just to text if it would work and it didn't. Could the issue be that a button is trying to segue and possibly display an alert at the same time?

Comment: "Could the issue be that a button is trying to segue and possibly display an alert at the same time" Yes.

Comment: @Halfmanhalfpie What should I do then? Is the a way for it to do both?

Comment: It seems a strange thing to want to do in the first place. The view controller that is being segued to has to display the alert, it cannot be StartMenuViewController if that is being segued from. If its not being segued from then it is fine.

Comment: @Halfmanhalfpie That's interesting. I wanted to use the alert to prevent them from advancing to the next view without filling the textfield. Do you think calling the alert and checking the textfield in a viewWillDisappear method will work?

Comment: You need to segue to the next view programmatically. If the textfield is nil display the alert, otherwise segue using code. Remove the segue from the button in the storyboard